# nginx + react static build path can't be accessed on direct url hit

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router-dom, react-admin

I'm trying to deploy a static build of my `create-react-app` using nginx. I've added `homepage: "."` as that is required.

And the final output is quite fine, except I can't access some URL directly.

**I'm using react-router-dom and react-admin:**

In `index.js`:

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Redirect to="/home"/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent}/>
            <Route path="/home" component={HomeComponent}/>
            <Route path="*">
                <Redirect to={"/login"}/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

In the `HomeComponent`, there is react-admin, it is also really simple:

```
<Admin
                    dataProvider={myDataProvider}
                    authProvider={myAuthProvider(this.props)}
                    layout={MyLayout}>
                    <Resource title="Users" name="users" list={UserList}/>
                    <Resource title="Transactions" name="transactions" list={TransactionList}/>
                </Admin>
```

[image: can be accessed - nginx]

But when I try to hit that URL directly:

[image: can't be accessed - nginx]

My `nginx.conf` file is quite simple:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:/etc/nginx# cat nginx.conf 
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

location / {
    error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error appears as nginx cannot match a file on the provided path `home#/transactions`.

Since you haven't provided your `nginx.conf` file. My assumption would be that you are missing a fallback in the `try_files` directive or the entire directive.

As you mentioned you are using `create-react-app`, that means your build output is a single `index.html` file and a bunch of static assets.

The following rule should match the static asset if it finds it and fallback to `index.html` if it doesn't exist, from where your frontend router will take care of the rest and show you the correct page.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

**UPDATE (OP added nginx.conf):**

The provided `nginx.conf` file's `location` block is not valid. `location` should be specified under a `server` block.

I noticed that in your `nginx.conf` file you are importing multiple other confs and it would've been useful to also add those since they might have an effect on the outcome. This import in particular caught my attention:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

This path can match `default.conf` if present, but I'm just guessing at this point. If it did and `default.conf` was unaltered, that would explain the behavior you are describing since `default.conf` looks like this:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  localhost;

   #charset koi8-r;
   #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

   location / {
       root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
       index  index.html index.htm;
   }

   #error_page  404              /404.html;

   # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
   #
   error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
       root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }

   # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
   #
   #location ~ \.php$ {
   #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
   #}

   # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
   #
   #location ~ \.php$ {
   #    root           html;
   #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
   #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
   #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
   #    include        fastcgi_params;
   #}

   # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
   # concurs with nginx's one
   #
   #location ~ /\.ht {
   #    deny  all;
   #}
}
```

There are a few possible solutions (assuming `default.conf` causes the issue):

1. Add `try_files` to the default config like so:

```
# default.conf

server {
   ...
   location / {
       root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       index  index.html index.htm;
   }
}
```

> If `default.conf` is shared with other configs, this is breaking for them

2. **(Preferred)** Omit the import of `default.conf` and add a custom server to `nginx.conf`. A server as simple as this will do the trick:

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        listen       80; # port
        server_name  _; # name
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html; # build dir
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad, I've added my conf file, I've added a 404 redirect rule in the conf file actually, can you please check again?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! I have updated my answer in response to adding the `nginx.conf` file.

Comment: Adding a 404 redirect will unfortunately make you lose your current url if accessing it directly, since it will always redirect you to the root. There might be use cases where this is not the appropriate behavior.

What you are attempting to do in the example is not really a 404 redirect, more like a custom 404 page which is the index, where nginx returns an OK response. This seems kind of hacky to me and unnecessary, since `try_files` already implements all of the logic needed.